# How to read a smart contract on Etherscan?

Tags: solidity, etherscan

I want to see the Solidity [source code for the smart contract located here](https://etherscan.io/address/0x09cabec1ead1c0ba254b09efb3ee13841712be14#readContract).

I expect to see Solidity source code. Something that has the following form and format:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

/**
 * @title Storage
 * @dev Store & retrieve value in a variable
 * @custom:dev-run-script ./scripts/deploy_with_ethers.ts
 */
contract Storage {

    uint256 number;

    /**
     * @dev Store value in variable
     * @param num value to store
     */
    function store(uint256 num) public {
        number = num;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Return value 
     * @return value of 'number'
     */
    function retrieve() public view returns (uint256){
        return number;
    }
}
```

But instead, I get something that looks like this:

[image]

The above picture looks like it might be just a list of all the variables or something? But it definitely doesn't look like the Solidity source code I'm seeking.

What am I doing wrong or not understanding? How can I view the Solidity source code?

Answer (score 0):

You're right in thinking *it might be just a list of variables*, if by "variables" you mean functions, mappings, etc... that are contained within the contract.

In answer to your question: there is no *100%* sure fire way of decompiling the ABI of a contract into it's solidity counterpart. You can try to use this [ABI Decompiler](https://Keccak256(function%20prototype)) or [this one](https://ethervm.io/decompile) or whatever you can find online that the community have built - however it's accuracy and/or reliability will never be a complete 100%. This is largely because of the way the EVM uses ABI/bytecode to interact with functions on a contract (by looking at the first 4 bytes of the Keccak256(function prototype)) which can result in false positives. It may also be because of the developer not having uploaded complete verified ABI to etherscan, or a plethora of other less common reasons.

If you are hoping to better understand [SAI](https://github.com/makerdao/sai) or [Uniswap](https://github.com/Uniswap) protocol, their Solidity code is viewable on github, along with many other protocols.

If you are going down the ABI route, you are able to generate a decoded version of the ABI using something like `ethers.js` and even display it in the console for examining. It may not be Solidity code, but you will be able to see all the cointents of the contract, including those which you would want to interact with.